# Sharing a post without permission on Facebook

Tags: facebook

One of my FB contacts has shared/posted pictures/posts from my page onto her page - without my permission.  How do I rectify this?  I have spoken to her without success.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- report it to fb as copyright infringement
- block her from individual posts or completely with your post audience.
- call them out on the shared posts directly “This is my content and you don’t have permission to share it. Be respectful and delete it.”
- make sure your sharing permissions are set up how you intend.

Always consider that pretty much nothing we put online is completely “safe.” Someone somewhere can screenshot it, copy it, share it, repackage it, and any number of other things we don’t explicitly give permission to and won’t always be taken seriously, unfortunately. Additionally, if this person wants to badly enough, they can always catfish and get your content in other ways.

Good wishes!

Answer (score 1):

1. First things first, was the plagiarised content your original creation?

   If yes, then simply report to Facebook. This is a clear-cut violation of their **Community Standards**, and she will have to take down the post.

   Even more, as she has voluntarily refused to take it down, you could escalate further, and get her account suspended or blocked.
2. If what you posted was in the public domain, or was in itself borrowed in part/ whole from some other source, then you do not own the copyright on it.

   Either the original content creator has to initiate action against her in this case ( which will also bring you into the red, as you have shared as well).

If it's under a freely shareable license (such as **Creative Commons** and there is a whole bunch of them, and each has different permission settings), then she is pretty much within her rights to share it.